# Easy Thumbnails - How to test a view that contains with ThumbnailerImageField in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, easy-thumbnails

I have a model called "Post" that looks for example like this:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from easy_thumbnails.fields import ThumbnailerImageField

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cover = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to='posts')
```

Then I have a serializer for the model:

```
# serializers.py

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cover = ThumbnailSerializer(alias='small')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'cover']
```

Using the Thumbnail serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from easy_thumbnails.templatetags.thumbnail import thumbnail_url


class ThumbnailSerializer(serializers.ImageField):
    """ Serializer for thumbnail creation using easy-thumbnails (Needed when using Django Rest Framework) """
    def __init__(self, alias, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.read_only = True
        self.alias = alias

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None

        url = thumbnail_url(value, self.alias)
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request is not None:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(url)

        return url
```

Finally I have a view:

```
# views.py

class PostView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(enabled=True)
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Now inside my test I try creating a post and fetching the data (im using PyTest):

```
# tests.py

def test_post_endpoint(client):
      post = Post.objects.create(
          name="Post 1",
          cover="posts/test_image.jpg",
      )

      response = client.get('/posts/')
      assert response.status_code == 200
      
      print(response.data['cover'])  
      # This prints:  http://testserver/posts/
      # Instead of:  http://testserver/posts/test_image.small.jpg
```

I also tried using:

```
cover=SimpleUploadedFile(
    name='test_image.jpg', 
    content=open(image_path, 'rb').read(), 
    content_type='image/jpeg'
)
```

But this ended up uploading the image to S3 which I dont want since its just a test and it should not upload anything to the cloud.

How can I get a proper response for the cover data? Something like this:

```
'http://testserver/posts/test_image.small.jpg'
```

Comment: Inside `to_representation`, what does `url` end up with?

Comment: to_representation returns an empty string when testing

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to modify Django's `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` path in the setting.py for test purposes. These values can be specified based on environment variables, like this:

```
# in settings.py
import os
...
if os.environ.get("TEST_ENV", '') == 'TRUE':
    MEDIA_URL = 'http://testserver'
    # or something like that
else:
    MEDIA_URL = '<your default url>'
```

before getting started with tests, the environment variable should be set:

```
export TEST_ENV=TRUE
```

[this blog post](https://dev.to/vlntsolo/how-to-split-django-settings-for-different-environments-18ad) might be helpful.

also, [Django's docs on how to handle files with MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_URL) may help.

[this third-party package for splitting Django settings](https://pypi.org/project/django-split-settings/) may also help.